# Popup dialog with event details keeps the same even if another id is used

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

I have integrated FullCalendar with JSON and PHP to get the events to a small calendar widget which works well.

I have coded a css/div popbox which is passed an event id via `eventClick` function so that when the event is clicked it opens and uses an ajax request with the passed id to get full event details into my focussed popbox.

I can close the popbox without any issue but when I click the next/previous/today tabs the calendar refreshes and also fires off the last viewed popbox.

I assume that it is because my calendar and ajax popbox are using the javascript event and are being tied together.

Can anyone help with a few lines to stop this?

My code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    cache: false,
    header: {left: 'title',center: '',right: 'today,prev,next'},
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
        $.getJSON("/mod/calendar/events.php?ts=1302604339",
            {
                action: "get_events",
                start: start.getTime(),
                end: end.getTime(),
                id: 'a',
                etype: "Club"
            },
            function(result){
                callback(result);
            }
        );
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvent){
        if (calEvent.txt) {
            Open_PopBox(calEvent.txt,'');
            return true;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    }       
});
```

The popbox code:

```
function Open_PopBox(id,r) {
    $("#popbox").css("height", $(document).height());
    //$("#cmt_u_pload").show(); 
    var str = "id="+id+"&r="+r; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/popbox.php",
        data: str,
        success: function(result){     
            $("#aj_popbox").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {       
                //$("#cmt_u_pload").hide();
                response = result.substring(0,3);
                if(result.substring(0,3)=="OK-"){           
                    len = result.length;
                    result = result.substring(3,len);
                }   
                $(this).html(result);
                $("#popbox").fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And the popbox is closed with this:

```
function Close_PopBox(){
    $("#popbox").fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with fullCalendar daily for two weeks now and found a few side effects.

You need to be carefull where you are calling your event from. Every time you click next/prev day, change views events are fired all over.. and for now they are not split.

What I mean is that anything that changes on the current view can trigger an event. I had a quick look at your code and your pop up box works ok.
Now when you click an button it will automatically fire your events.
I got a bit lost at the point where

```
function(result){callback(result);});},
```

begins ?.. mainly because I do not use it like that. That could be the cause why it is firing the last event.

Maybe try this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
             header: {
                 left: 'today',
                 center: 'prev,title,next',
                 right: 'month,basicDay'
             },
             eventClick: function( event, jsEvent, view )
             { 
                Open_PopBox(event.txt,'')
                },
            events: '/mod/calendar/events.php?ts=1302604339'

            });
```

Inside the eventClick you can check what event or view is calling your function.
jsEvent can show you the source click info.

breaking it down like this will be easier to debug.

Hope this helps.